# C++ map insert problem with objects containing another map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have unordered map containers containing another maps.

```
using name = std::string;
using stop_o = std::pair<name, std::unordered_map<key,/**/ std::pair<name, std::unordered_map<key, std::pair<name, std::map<packed_time, std::pair<packed_time, std::pair < int, std::map<int, std::pair<int, std::pair<packed_time, std::pair<name, timetable*>>>>>>>>>>>>;
using platform_o = std::pair<name, std::unordered_map<key,/**/ std::pair<name, std::map<packed_time, std::pair<packed_time, std::pair < int, std::map<int, std::pair<int, std::pair<packed_time, std::pair<name, timetable*>>>>>>>>>>;
using platform_route_o = std::pair<name, std::map<packed_time,/**/ std::pair<packed_time, std::pair < int, std::map<int, std::pair<int, std::pair<packed_time, std::pair<name, timetable*>>>>>>>>;
using route_departure_o = std::pair<packed_time,/**/ std::pair < int, std::map<int, std::pair<int, std::pair<packed_time, std::pair<name, timetable*>>>>>>;
using trip_o = std::pair < int, std::map<int,/**/ std::pair<int, std::pair<packed_time, std::pair<name, timetable*>>>>>;
using trip_departure_o = std::pair<int, std::pair<packed_time, std::pair<name, timetable*>>>;
```

trip_o is just a pair of int and trip_departure_o.
Then I am using containers:

```
using stop_container = std::unordered_map<key, stop_o>;
using platform_container = std::unordered_map<key, platform_o>;
using platform_route_container = std::unordered_map<key, platform_route_o>;
using route_departure_container = std::map<packed_time, route_departure_o>;
using trip_container = std::unordered_map < int, trip_o>;
using trip_departure_container = std::map<int, trip_departure_o>;

// main object - put something inside
class timetable {
    public:
    stop_container timetable_stops;
    trip_container timetable_trips;
};
```

My code is:

```
void read_timetable(timetable& tt, std::istream& ifs)
{
    std::string line, token;
    ifs.ignore(1000, '\n');
    while (std::getline(ifs, line, '\n'))
    {
        std::vector<std::string> v;
        std::stringstream entry(line);
        while (std::getline(entry, token, '\t'))
        {
            v.push_back(token);
        }
        std::vector<int> time;
        std::stringstream t(v[5]);
        while (std::getline(t, token, ':'))
        {
            time.push_back(stoi(token));
        }
        packed_time pt = pack_time(time[0], time[1]);

        if (tt.timetable_stops.find(v[4]) == tt.timetable_stops.end())
        {
            trip_departure_o td;
            td.first = stoi(v[2]);
            td.second.first = pt;
            td.second.second.first = v[4];
            td.second.second.second = &tt;

            trip_o tr;
            tr.first = stoi(v[1]);
            tr.second.insert({ stoi(v[1]), td });
            std::cout << tr.second.at(stoi(v[1])).first << std::endl;

            route_departure_o rd;
            rd.first = pt;
            rd.second = tr;
            std::cout << rd.second.first << std::endl;

            platform_route_o pr;
            pr.first = v[0];
            pr.second.insert({ pt, rd });
            std::cout << pr.second.at(pt).first << std::endl;

            platform_o p;
            p.first = v[3];
            p.second.insert({ v[3], pr });

            stop_o s;
            s.first = v[4];
            s.second.insert({ v[4], p });
            std::cout << s.second.at(v[4]).first << std::endl;

            tt.timetable_stops.insert({ v[4], s });

            std::cout << tt.timetable_stops.at(v[4]).second.at(v[3]).first;
            }
        }
... .. .
```

I split line from input to 6 tokens everytime. Then I convert last token(time) to hours and minutes and pack it to one int.
Now goes the problem. I succesfully create trip_departure td, with test outputs I know that there are all variables in it. Then I initialize trip_o tr. First variable is there, but when I want to getthe second one which is in fact the previous object td, I get an error:

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCBF09D759 in jr.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location 0x0000007FF891D410.

The exception is thrown on this line:

```
std::cout << tt.timetable_stops.at(v[4]).second.at(v[3]).first;
```

It looks like it wasnt inserted to the map. But why?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Please provide a [mre]. At a guess one of your `stoi` calls is failing due to non-numerical strings

Comment: Yes I tried, which stoi, why?

Comment: Without a [mre] its difficult to tell, your debugger should stop on the unhandled exception, examine the call stack to find out where the exception is being thrown from

Comment: Yeah, the exception is thrown on this line: std::cout << tr.second.at(stoi(v[4])).first;

Comment: If you print the strings you're trying to convert before trying, you could spot which one is wrong.

Comment: the 4 instead of 1 in v[], thanks

Comment: Where are the test outputs referred to in "with test outputs I know that there are all variables in it"?

Comment: I have edited the answer, the exception is thrown, when I want to read from object reference &tt which is input parameter of this method.

Comment: we still don't have a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles is there a problem when inserting a map of maps into paramter of method? It seems that all objects are okay only the last tt.timetable not, it contains platforms, but these platforms does not contain other maps, however the sooner initialized platform yes

Comment: @Rikib161999 You do not need such complex code to demonstrate "inserting a map of maps into paramter of method". A [mre] would focus on just that one thing you are interested in and add just enough context (declarations/definitions) for the code to be complete. I cannot see **thirteen** type aliases being necessary to demonstrate a map of maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the second `at`, with `v[3]`.

The first `at` returns a reference to the copy of `s` that was added to the timetable stops. That copy has an element at `v[4]`, not `v[3]`. So you either want

```
tt.timetable_stops.at(v[4]).second.at(v[4])
```

or

```
tt.timetable_stops.at(v[4]).second.at(v[4]).second.at(v[3])
//                 ^ returns copy of s
//                                  ^ returns copy of { v[4], p } originally stored in s
// returns copy of p stored in ...                 ^
```

This would be easier to see and diagnose if you'd use proper structures with appropriately named members rather than a complicated mass of type aliases.